# How can I use queueable Apex instead of a future method with arguments?

Tags: apex, callout, future

I have an `@future` class, `SubmitOnApproval` which is called when an opportunity is approved. This class is below:

public without sharing class SubmitOnApproval {

```
@future 
public static void oppRecordsToSubmit(id oppId){        
        Opportunity o = [select id, recordtype.DeveloperName from Opportunity where id = : oppId];
        if(o.recordtype.DeveloperName!='PIP_Finished_Product'){
            List<GT_Quote__c> oppQuote = new List<GT_Quote__c>();
            oppQuote = [Select id, opportunity__c, Submit_Request_Picklist__c, Product__c
                          from GT_Quote__c
                          where opportunity__c = :oppId 
                          and Submit_Request_Picklist__c = 'Draft'
                          and Product__c != ''
                          and Quote_Stage__c = 'Request Pending'];

            if(oppQuote.size()>0){            
                for(GT_Quote__c quote : oppQuote){
                    quote.Submit_Request_Picklist__c = 'Submit';
                }   
                database.update(oppQuote, True);
            }
        }
        else{
            List<Opportunity_Application__c> oppAppsToSubmit = new List<Opportunity_Application__c>();

            oppAppsToSubmit = [select id, Submit_Request__c 
                               from Opportunity_Application__c
                               where Submit_Request__c = 'Draft' 
                               and Opportunity__c = :oppId];

            if(oppAppsToSubmit.size()>0){
                for(Opportunity_Application__c oa : oppAppsToSubmit){
                    oa.Submit_Request__c = 'Submit';
                }
                database.update(oppAppsToSubmit, True);
            }
        }                               

}


@future 
public static void oppRecordsToCancel(id oppId){
        Opportunity ocancel = [select id, StageName, recordtype.DeveloperName from Opportunity where id = : oppId];
        system.debug('rtrtrt'+ ocancel.recordtype.DeveloperName);           

            List<GT_Quote__c> cancelledQuotes = new List<GT_Quote__c>();  

            cancelledQuotes = [Select id, opportunity__c, Submit_Request_Picklist__c
                                from GT_Quote__c
                                where opportunity__c = :oppId and Submit_Request_Picklist__c = 'Draft'];


            for(GT_Quote__c quote : cancelledQuotes){
                quote.Quote_Stage__c = 'Request Cancelled';
            }   
            if(cancelledQuotes.size()>0){             
                database.update(cancelledQuotes, True);

}
```

I am trying to use an `@future` class, `QuoteRestCallouts`, to generate some XML and then make `POST` call to an external webservice (Vendavo). That class is below:

```
public class QuoteRestCallouts{

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void makePostCallout(List<Id> quoteRecords) {
        String body = ''; //data to send to external service
        String xmlstring = '';

        String xmlns = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
        String soapNS = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
        String tns = 'http://www.vendavo.com/ws/types';
        String xsd = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema';
        String xsi = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';

        for (Id quoteId : quoteRecords) {       
            GT_Quote__c q = [SELECT Id, 
                             Name
                             //MORE FIELDS HERE
                             FROM GT_Quote__c WHERE id=:quoteId];

            //GENERATE SOME XML HERE

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setTimeout(120000); 
            req.setEndpoint('callout:Vendavo_Integration');
            req.setMethod('POST');

            req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/text');        
            req.setBodyDocument(doc);
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse res;

            try {
                res = http.send(req);

                if (res.getStatusCode() < 200 || res.getStatusCode() > 300) {
                    displayResponseAndSendErrorEmail();

                } else {
                    displayResponseAndSendErrorEmail();
                }
            }
            catch (System.CalloutException e) {
                displayResponseAndSendErrorEmail();
            } 
        }
    }
```

My `QuoteAfterUpdate` trigger generates the quoteRecords list used in `QuoteRestCallouts`. The problem is that `SubmitOnApproval` triggers `QuoteAfterUpdate` which tries to call `QuoteRestCallouts` and I run into the problem of calling 2 `@future` methods in the same transaction.

Can I use queueable apex in some way? I have looked for some examples but I can't figure out how to pass a parameter i.e. `quoteRecords` to the execute method. I want the below ideally:

```
public void execute(QueueableContext context, List<Id> quoteRecords) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Also we are using a custom quote object as SFDC didn't have the standard object when ours was implemented.

Thanks for any help

Comment: N.B. `if(oppQuote.size()>0)` and `if(oppAppsToSubmit.size()>0){` and `if(cancelledQuotes.size()>0){` are all superfluous; no DML is burned on empty lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_queueable

The trailhead really does go over this well in terms of understanding utilizing parameters in future and Queueable.

[image]